# NodeJS mySQL showing old data sets

Tags: mysql, discord.js

Its been a day since ive been trying to fix this but i cant figure it out.

This successfully inputs into the table if user id isnt already in it.

```
   con.query(`SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ${user}`, (err, rows) => {
       if(err) throw err;

       let sql;

       if(rows.length <1) {
       sql = `INSERT INTO user (id, xp) VALUES (${user}, ${genXP})`;
    }

 con.query(sql)
});
```

but when trying to read from it using this

```
function queryXP() {
    con.query(`SELECT xp FROM user WHERE id = ${user}`, (err, rows) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    planID = rows
  });
}
```

It always outputs this even after restart of bot and mysql

```
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

Error: ER_EMPTY_QUERY: Query was empty
```

If i check it manually it clearly exists

```
MariaDB [bot]> select * from user;
+--------------------+------+
| id                 |  xp  |
+--------------------+------+
| 355871581752524801 |    4 |
| 193289250068889600 |    4 |
| 305921615282307083 |    1 |
| 693853122728296538 |    1 |
+--------------------+------+
4 rows in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [bot]>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong here but isn't `xp` in the query supposed to be capital? It shows up capital in the table you posted at the bottom

Comment: sorry it supposed to be in lowecase when i pasted it here it looked weird so i had to re type some stuff. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Try to console.log `user`, does that return anything?